# load content to DIV tag on demand

Tags: jquery, animation, html

I have a "comments" section on a webpage that I have hidden initially and when the user clicks the comments link the div tag (and comments) appear using the jQuery show/hide functions.

My question is: is it possible to load this content only when the comments link is clicked (not when the entire page is loaded)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that `comments_link` and `comments_container` are the respective IDs:

```
$('#comments_link').click(function() {
     $('#comments_container').load('some-awesome-url-here');
});
```

This technique uses Ajax to make a request to a URL asynchronously and injects the resulting HTML into the specified element.

See [`jQuery.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes... The technology you need to use is called Ajax.  You can do it with jQuery or using the XMLHttpRequest object directly (not recommended).

What server technology are you using. e.g. php, .net, java,...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use [jQuery's `load()` function](http://api.jquery.com/load/).